# Proving that sigma-algebra containing open intervals contains semi-closed intervals

Tags: measure-theory

I know that if it contains all open intervals, then it necessarily has all closed intervals (that's easy) - we know it has all intervals $(a,b)$. It must also contain $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty)$. It also has the union of $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty)$, and its complement is a closed interval $[a,b]$.

How to show that in also contains all semi-closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$?

That would prove it contains all possible intervals, because there are no other types of intervals than open, closed and semi-closed.

Comment: $$(a,b]=\bigcap_n(a,b+1/n)\qquad[a,b)=\bigcap_n(a-1/n,b)\qquad [a,\infty)=\bigcup_n[a,n]\qquad\text{and so on...}$$

Comment: how is the idea to make a union of $$[a,b]U(b,+\infty) = [a,+\infty)$$ - which is semiclosed. But how to show all, I am thinking.